# How to decode Json in python and iterate

Tags: php, python, arrays, json

I am new in python,I am sending a php json encoded array to python
like this:

```
$myArray = array(1,5,8,6);
$jsonArray = json_encode($myArray);

exec("python ".$absPath."/myPythonFile.py $absPath $parm $jsonArray",$out);
```

Here is the python code:

```
from pydfs_lineup_optimizer import *
import sys
import json

optimizer = LineupOptimizer(FanDuelBasketballSettings)
optimizer.load_players_from_CSV("test_new.json")
try:
    players_that_you_want = []
    for number in sys.argv[3]:
        print number
    lineups = optimizer.optimize()
    for l in lineups:
        print(l)
except LineupOptimizerException as e:
    print(e)
```

When I am trying to print `number` variable inside python file,This is how python returning:

```
[
1
,
5
,
8
,
6
]
```

and I want it like this:

```
1
5
8
6
```

Any Idea What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything to decode the JSON.

Comment: `.load_players_from_CSV` sounds like a CSV decoder; JSON is not a form of CSV. Pythonhas excellent JSON decoding and encoding functions in the `json` module. However, since you're just transporting a simple integer array, why bother encoding it as JSON?

Comment: He's not actually asking about the function `load_players_from_CSV()`, though. He wants to know why `print number` is outputting `[`, `1`, `,`, `5`, etc... instead of `1`, `5`, `8`, `6`.

Comment: @chuck exactly.When I am sending json encoded array from php so why its converting as a string in python.Any idea guys

Comment: @Rahul, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is being sent in as a string, so you're not actually splitting it into the proper values with your loop. You can try stripping the square brackets and using `split(',')`.

```
input = "[1,2,3,4]"
processed_input = input.strip('[]').split(',')
```

The above code will do the job.

Comment: Yes,you gave the right direction and I got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we need to do:

```
from pydfs_lineup_optimizer import *
import sys
import json

optimizer = LineupOptimizer(FanDuelBasketballSettings)
optimizer.load_players_from_CSV("test_new.json")
try:
    players_that_you_want = []
    for number in json.loads(sys.argv[3]):
        print number
    lineups = optimizer.optimize()
    for l in lineups:
        print(l)
except LineupOptimizerException as e:
    print(e)
```